# Not able to enable FT2232h (FTDI) Pin

Tags: python-3.x, ftdi

I am trying to enable ft2232h ftdi pin for my project application but i am not getting high pulse on oscilloscope. I am using below python code and link through visual studio....

https://iosoft.blog/2018/12/02/ftdi-python-part-1/

However i am detecting ftdi like:
PS C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\codes> python -u "c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\codes\work\pyftdi\pyftdi\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
{'type': 7, 'id': 67330065, 'description': b'Quad RS232-HS B', 'serial': b'B'}
PS C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\codes>

Please help me to enable ftdi pin with python code on visual studio.

```
import sys, ftd2xx as ftd
d = ftd.open(0)    # Open first FTDI device
print(d.getDeviceInfo())
OP = 0x01            # Bit mask for output D0
d.setBitMode(OP, 1)  # Set pin as output, and async bitbang mode
d.write(str(OP))     # Set output high
d.write(str(0))      # Set output low
```